# Calculate Distance (Not Squared) between two vectors using Inner Product

Tags: matrices, vectors, inner-products

I'm stuck on a Inner Product question:
Calculate the distance (non squared) between $x=[4 2 1]$ and $y=[0 1 0]$
using inner product defined as
[image]

Can someone kindly help with the solution?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** One you have computed the vector $v = x - y$, compute the square of the distance as
$$
\|x - y\|^2 = \|v\|^2 = \langle v,v \rangle = v^T\pmatrix{2&1&0\\1&2&-1\\0&-1&2}v.
$$
Because this is the square of the distance, you must find the square root of the resulting number to get your answer.

Comment: Hey!
I'm clear on the multiplication part, but since the question has asked for non-squared distance, I do not understand what it means. Your method does yield the correct answer, but I'm unable to grasp the meaning of non-squared distance.

Comment: @Aman The "non-squared distance" just means "the distance". The term non-squared is to contrast it to the "squared distance", which would be the quantity $\langle v,v \rangle$ that you computed first.

Comment: Okay! Thanks a lot for the clarification.